# Get all order details from getItems() / getAllItems() / getAllVisibleItems()

Tags: magento2, orders, cart, sales-order

I am trying to get all the order data.
So I came across these three different types of methods to get items from an order

- `getItems()`
- `getAllItems()`
- `getAllVisibleItems()`

I tried the first two `getItems()` and `getAllItems` , they give me double entries of order

- `One with no size`
- `Another with 0 price`

*code*

```
    foreach ($orderInfo->getAllItems() as $item):?>
    // code to get all order attributes
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: double order details entry]

and when I tried last option `getAllVisibleItems()` I get a single entry(which I need), but `size` is missing.

*code*

```
    foreach ($orderInfo->getAllVisibleItems() as $item):?>
    // code to get all order attributes
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

So on some exploration, I found that `getAllVisibleItems()` gives me `configurable product` which doesn't have the size,

So how can I get all order details in a single entry which contain every order related details

*Item Name* , *Size* , *Quantity* , *Price*
I am puzzled how can I get all these details.

Comment: Did my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261634/76597 help you or do you need further help?

Comment: i did same before your answer, anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `getAllVisibleItems()` is the right way. If you have a configurable product you can get the configured options with the following code:

```
if ($item->getProductType() == 'configurable'){
    $options = $item->getProductOptions()['attributes_info'];
}
```

There you find an array with the following structure in case of a configurable product - what you need for frontend are all the lables and values of the elements of this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => Size
        [value] => XS
        [option_id] => 141
        [option_value] => 167
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => Color
        [value] => Red
        [option_id] => 93
        [option_value] => 58
    )

)
```

Comment: Do you know how I would get the same infor but for a bundle product?